# How does Synthesia detect instrument name if the file does not contain any instrument name meta event?

Tags: midi, file-format

I am working with [this](https://pastebin.com/cnewJLTr) midi file. And I see that synthesia detects 2 recorders, 2 cellos and 1 contrabass for each one of the midi tracks respectively, but there is no any 'instrument name' meta event in the midi file.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIDI specification itself does not define what instrument a program change message maps to.
MIDI files are supposed to contain a System Exclusive message that initializes the synthesizer for the desired standard (e.g., "GM System On" for General MIDI, or "XG Reset" for the XG standed).

This file does not contain such an initialization. But most files are for General MIDI (and most other standards are compatible with GM), so Synthesia assumes that the MIDI file is for a synthesizer that supports General MIDI, and just takes the name from the [GM instrument list](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/gm-level-1-sound-set).

Answer (score 0):

The General MIDI specification gives a default assignment of actual instruments to instrument numbers - instrument #44 is a contrabass, for example.  MIDI files would have absolutely no portability between different systems otherwise.

Comment: but where is that #44 for contrabass, or, in this example, 0x4A of the recorder? in the program change midi event at the start of each midi track, I found out.